# Keep alive sessions created with Python API

Tags: python, api

I created a session using the following script:

```py
import dolphindb as ddb
s = ddb.session()
s.connect("localhost", 8848)
```

The session often got disconnected when interacting with the DolphinDB server. How can I keep the session alive for a specified period of time?

Comment: If you don't do more work with the connection (session), it may be released when your program ends

Comment: Try lowering the `keepAliveTime` to 10 seconds, but since you're on localhost, this shouldn't be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In usual circumstances, sessions created with `ddb.session` will not get disconnected.

DolphinDB Python API provides the following parameters to keep sessions alive in case of network error:

(1) keepAliveTime and reconnect of the `connect` function

keepAliveTime - specifies the duration between two keepalive transmissions to detect the TCP connection status. Set the parameter to release half-open TCP connections timely when the network is unstable. The default value is 30 (seconds). For example, when you set keepAliveTime to 50, the session would not got disconnected if the network was down for 30 seconds.

reconnect - When set to true, Python API tries to reconnect the session to the server when a connection error is detected.

(2) `ddb.session.setTimeout()`

Only available on Linux

The static method `setTimeout` of the Session object specifies the TCP connection timeout period (in seconds) before the peer acknowledges (ACK) receiving the data packets. After the timeout period expires, the TCP connection is closed. It is equivalent to the TCP_USER_TIMEOUT option. The default value is 30. If the value is specified as 0, TCP will use the system default.

Use `ddb.session.setTimeout()` in the following data transmission scenarios:

Your network bandwidth is full and the amount of data you want to transmit is large

One-time transmission of a large amount of data. Transmitting a large amount of data takes a lot of time and, as a result, ACK may not be received in time. After the timeout period expires, the system closes the TCP connection (the session).